# How to configure CPLEX on Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, cplex

I want to configure CPLEX on Netbeans using Java but when I run a test example,I get the following error message :

[image]

**What I did** : I added the CPLEX Jar library by a right click on Libraries and then Add JAR/Folder. Then I went in Run->Set Project Configuration -> Customize and in the arguments, I added

> -Djava.library.path = C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1271\cplex\bin\x64_win64\cplex1271.dll

Could someone help me ?

Comment: Which versions of Java and NetBeans are you using?

Comment: @skomisa I properly checked the VM options and now the error message has for beginning : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Pierre\Desktop\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1271\cplex\bin\x64_win64\cplex1271.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform. So I will install a x64 Java version, hope it is the problem

Comment: @skomisa Indeed it was the error : java 32 bits instead of 64 was used. Lost my afternoon ;-(

Answer (score -1):

it's impossible to access cplex version 12.8 in netbeans , you have two solution 
change cplex or try in other editeur like eclipse or intellij idea